# select:focus{width:auto;}

Tags: css, select, focus, width

I have a css problem and I don't know how to fix it.
In order to expand a dropdown list you must use css below. Work fine only with one condition, when you select an option the select wont return to initial width. WHY??? :(
This a behavior that I want to happen on all browser including IE8 because of IE I must set width on focus .

```
select:focus{
    min-width:158px;
    width:auto;
}
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/304/

Comment: "when you select an option the select wont return to initial width" - how are you ding this?

Comment: expand the select in order to chose an option from list, after you've selected an option from the list, the select remain expanded on auto width and not to original size ...

Comment: Maybe you want to be using `:hover` instead of `:focus`. As mentioned by @Wombat, the select box is focused until you click on something else

Comment: hmmmm interesting, but in IE8 doesn't work

Comment: Good point - select boxes in IE appear to be difficult little critters.

Comment: yes IE is a stupid browser but almost all companies of the world use for their internal apps that stupid browser:(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out! I think will solve your problems regarding combo boxes on IE.

http://www.andreabianchin.it/jquery-skinner/

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the element to lose focus after it changes.

Add:

```
onchange="this.blur()"
```

like this:

```
<select id="id72" class="styleDDC" onchange="this.blur()">
```

Comment: I cannot use this example because in my app i have a lots of pop-up modals and if I modify in each html page I will be old before to finish my job :((. I need to do something from css , even a jQuery plugin will be fine :) . Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

the pseudo css class: focus is for while its selected (while its highlighted blue) once you click on something else it shrinks back down to your min-width

Comment: yes, I know that but I have an textarea on left and on focus remain overridden by select width auto.

Comment: ok, why do you want it to expand? i mean technically once someone clicks on it they'll be able to see all the options available to them so making it expand when it doesn't seem necessary seems odd

Comment: I want that because I use this control (select)  to keep some mobile offers with a long description and if is not expanding the offers description cannot be read. And I want to return on the original width on click because override the other control.

Comment: hmmm...ok so you're saying that when your users click on the select box you want it to expand so they'll be able to read the description of an offer if it has one,but once selected it should shrink back down the min-width right?

Comment: also :hover is buggy in ie8, but it looks like your only non-js solution

Comment: here is a jquery way that can be used in an external file:$('.styleDDC').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('width','auto');
},function(){
        $(this).css('width','158px');
    })

Comment: here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/308/ this way you wont have to use it inline but can use it on every page and in ie7 and 8